# Getting a sum of distinct counts from two databases

Tags: mysql

first question, hoping someone can help here. I've been trying to track down how to do this for a bit and figured it was time to ask for an assist. Please note I'm very new to My SQL queries and my code is probably as inelegant as it gets!

I'm working with two databases with identical configurations. Each database represents regional data but all tables and columns are identical between them. In essence I'm looking to get a daily count of activities performed by a specific individual. Also, the data I need to gather is on multiple tables so bear with me s I make my notations here: D_USA and D_CAN for the two databases, T1 and T2 for the two tables I'm joining. Here is my existing code and the output I get:

```
SELECT 
  "USA" AS REGION, 
  LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(D_USA.T1.date),10) as DATE,
  D_USA.T1.owner AS OWNER, COUNT(DISTINCT D_USA.T1.id) AS GROUPS, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT D_USA.T2.id) AS UNITS
FROM
  D_USA.T1
  JOIN D_USA.T2 ON D_USA.T1.id = D_USA.T2.parent_id
WHERE
  D_USA.T1.complete='Y'
  AND D_USA.T1.owner = 'XYZ' 
  AND D_USA.T2.status = 'P' 
  AND LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(D_USA.T1.date),10) >= '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY DATE
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  "CAN" AS REGION, 
  LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(D_CAN.T1.date),10) as DATE,
  D_CAN.T1.owner AS OWNER, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT D_CAN.T1.id) AS GROUPS, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT D_CAN.T2.id) AS UNITS
FROM
  D_CAN.T1
  JOIN D_CAN.T2 ON D_CAN.T1.id = D_CAN.T2.parent_id
WHERE 
  D_CAN.T1.complete='Y'
  AND D_CAN.T1.owner = 'XYZ' 
  AND D_CAN.T2.status = 'P' 
  AND LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(D_CAN.T1.date),10) >= '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY DATE 
ORDER BY DATE ASC;
```

Current Output:

```
REGION|DATE|OWNER|GROUPS|UNITS
USA|2012-01-01|XYZ|10|100
CAN|2012-01-01|XYZ|5|100
USA|2012-01-02|XYZ|10|75
USA|2012-01-03|XYZ|5|50
CAN|2012-01-03|XYZ|10|50
CAN|2012-01-04|XYZ|10|100
```

Desired Output (based on above)

```
DATE|OWNER|GROUPS|UNITS
2012-01-01|XYZ|15|200
2012-01-02|XYZ|10|75
2012-01-03|XYZ|15|100
2012-01-04|XYZ|10|100
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'd probably fare better having a single table with a column that indicates to which region each record relates.  However, if you make your existing query a *subquery* to a parent that performs the grouping, you should get what you need.

Comment: Rather than do string manipulations to get your dates, use the `DATE()` function to return the date portion and strip off the time. That way, you are doing comparisons of actual date values rather than string comparisons  `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(D_CAN.T1.date)) >= '2012-01-01'`

Comment: unfortunately we have to keep the regional data separate for business purposes. I agree that a regional column would be easier, but not feasible right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap a select round it as in

Select Date,Owner,Groups, Sum(Units) as Units
From (insert your query in here) somedummyName
Group By Date,Owner,Groups